# FactoryBot Rails how to fill out 'belong to' field when creating a record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd

I have Group and User model and trying to create corresponding factories for testing.

```
FactoryBot.define do |variable|
  factory :group do
    name { Faker::Name.name }
  end   
end
```

Since a user belongs to a group, I need to give it an integer value (a group ID) but can't figure out how. From my Laravel background, this is what I'm expecting...

```
FactoryBot.define do |variable|
  factory :user do
    email { Faker::Internet.unique.email}
    name { Faker::Name.name }
    password { Faker::Internet.password }
    # Grab a first group record in the database or create a new one and return its ID.
    group_id : # ????
  end
end
```

This is my first programming with Ruby and Ruby on Rails, I'm googling so hard to make it done. What's the syntax for this?

Also, is this the best way to write a factory with associations?

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-json-api-with-rails-5-part-one

Here's a tutorial I just found and it's giving nil for todo_id.  Would it automatically generate a Todo using a factory and give it an ID?  There's no clear explanation on why.  Thanks.

Comment: [associations](https://devhints.io/factory_bot#associations)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the proper syntax:

```
FactoryBot.define do |variable|
  factory :user do
    email { Faker::Internet.unique.email}
    name { Faker::Name.name }
    password { Faker::Internet.password }
    group
  end
end
```

If you do not specify a `group`, FactoryBot will create or build a `group` for you, as appropriate, whenever you create or build a `user`.

If you do specify a `group`, FactoryBot will use the `group` you specify.

Answer (score 0):

in your testing, but not in factory, you can use this

```
  group = FactoryBot.create(:group)
  user = FactoryBot.create(:user, group: group)
```

or you want to try to get the first group that you created

```
  group = Group.first # i'm not sure, but you can try this
  user = FactoryBot.create(:user, group: group)
```